# Bootstrap Modal header and footer not attached to body

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

My bootsrap modal is attempting to launch an embedded google maps iframe. In the header I have a close button and in the footer I have another close button.

The issue is that the header and footer do not attach properly to the modal-body where the map is contained. I even tried it by removing the iframe. The iframe is now the issue since even with a white background and nothing in the body it still doesn't line up correctly.

Here is an image of what is happening: [image]

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div id="ModalCabotoMap" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">

         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
          </div>

      </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <iframe id="CabotoMap" src="https://www.google.com/maps/..."></iframe>
          </div>

     <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

/* Get iframe src attribute value i.e. YouTube video url
and store it in a variable */
var url = $("#CabotoMap").attr('src');


/* Assign the initially stored url back to the iframe src
attribute when modal is displayed again */

  $("#ModalCabotoMap").on('show.bs.modal', function(){
    $("#CabotoMap").attr('src', url);
  });

  $('#ModalCabotoMap').on('shown', function () {
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  });
});
```

Comment: I think you are closing your modal-content div after the modal header div. try to include the modal head, body and footer inside the modal-content.

Comment: @RossiRobinsion you are the real MVP! You were correct, I was closing the modal body div too early. It looks perfect now.

Please post your reply as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Comment: This happens but we learn. Glad to have you got the success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @Badrush's comment, I am posting this answer. The .modal-content was prematurely closed after .modal-header so the modal was not properly displayed. After putting .modal-header, .modal-body and .modal-footer in the .modal-content, it renders perfectly.

```
<div id="ModalCabotoMap" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
               <iframe id="CabotoMap" src="https://www.google.com/maps/..."></iframe>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>

        </div>

     </div>
</div>
```